# Select distinct. Most suitable technique to reduce wait time

Tags: postgresql, indexing, django-models, partitioning

I have lots of rows in my table in Postgres DB.

I make insertions in this table every 20 minutes, clear old entries every day and have only 2 selection options from it.

So I want to optimise time, that I wait for my selections.

First selection is kind of:

```
Select * from table where item=<item_id>
```

Second is kind of:

```
Select distinct(datetime) from table
```

So, in order to optimize 1 selection, I may make **indexies** for `item` field. As I understood this technique works perfectly for queries where smth `equals` smth.

But I don't know how to optimise my 2 selection query. I think smth like **partitioning** should help me, but there are several types of partitioning and I am a bit confused.

**So what is the best option to optimize my queries?**

Also, I am using python and Django models. If there is a good library that may do all the dirty job. That would be great. Most suitable now, that I found: http://architect.readthedocs.io/

**Edit1**
Thanks to Evan Carrol.

Tried to use index for second query.
Command:

```
explain analyze select distinct time_updated from wow_auction_gordunni
```

Gives:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=335091.65..335092.51 rows=86 width=8) (actual time=4246.582..4246.607 rows=91 loops=1)
  Group Key: time_updated
  ->  Seq Scan on wow_auction_gordunni  (cost=0.00..313574.92 rows=8606692 width=8) (actual time=0.047..2257.979 rows=8616562 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.080 ms
Execution time: 4246.675 ms
```

Then creating index and vacuum:

```
Create INDEX ON wow_auction_gordunni (time_updated);
VACUUM ANALYZE wow_auction_gordunni;
explain analyze select distinct time_updated from wow_auction_gordunni;
```

Gives following:

```
Unique  (cost=0.43..249907.42 rows=92 width=8) (actual time=0.057..3537.626 rows=92 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using wow_auction_gordunni_time_updated_idx on wow_auction_gordunni  (cost=0.43..228163.42 rows=8697599 width=8) (actual time=0.055..2488.408 rows=8696562 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 85796
Planning time: 0.726 ms
Execution time: 3537.800 ms
```

So it seems that index helps a bit (postgres started to use index), but not dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use an index scan so long as it makes sense. Sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT
    x%3 AS x,
    repeat( md5(x::text)::text, 200 ) AS t1
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS t(x);

CREATE INDEX ON foo (x);
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;
```

Query,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT x FROM Foo;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=0.42..28480.42 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=0.034..257.734 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_x_idx on foo  (cost=0.42..25980.42 rows=1000000 width=32) (actual time=0.031..122.668 rows=1000000 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.090 ms
 Execution time: 257.764 ms
(5 rows)
```

So to optimize your second selection query, create an index on datetime. Check out the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. See if it gets use an an index. If that doesn't help or the index isn't being used you can try to `set enable_seqscan = off` and then rerunning the query. Now you know what the savings would be, if any. You can paste both plans here and we can take a look at it.

Comment: This will only work if the table has been vacuumed recently and nothing much has changed, IOW if PostgreSQL *knows* that almost all tuples in the index are visible to everyone.

Comment: Thanks for commands.
Don't know about `vacuum analyze` and what means data after this `explain analyze` command. Will dig in them and try this day.

Comment: Tried to make an index. Updated question. It helps, but not very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to optimize the second query, it has to scan the whole table to find all possible values of `datetime`.

The best you can do is to see that the table is not bloated by clearing the table with `TRUNCATE` rather than `DELETE`, and to put enough RAM into the machine so that the whole table is in RAM.

Comment: It doesn't have to scan the whole table. It may very well do that, but it doesn't have too.

Comment: True. But then it has to scan the whole index. But you're right, if the index is small, that will make it somewhat faster.